# How do I configure Blender 2D view?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, customization, keymap

I had a previous version of Blender in which I was able to configure it to Alt + Right Click and it would activate 2D View and which ever direction I would drag to, it would snap the camera to that side of the model (X axis, Y, -X, Z, and so forth...).

However I downloaded the latest version of blender and uninstalled the previous version, forgetting to export my key configurations.
I've been looking everywhere to reconfigure it back the way it was but I can't remember how I did it and I am having a lot of trouble. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "2D view"? If you mean front, side or top view of your 3D object just use the numpad keys or click one of the gizmo letters in the top-right corner of the 3D view. You can also ALT-MMB drag to change the view.

Comment: By 2D View, I meant exactly what you described. Is there a named for that? I'm sorry, I am a 3ds Max user and I'm not too sure of the terminology in the Blender community.

The problem is that I already mapped ALT-MMB drag to be the camera rotate and MMB to pan camera, as it is the default key-binds on 3ds Max, which I am most familiar with. 

I know I was able at some point to configure it so that I could used ALT-RMB drag to activate this front, side, top viewmode. I just really don't remember where to find this category in the key-bind menu.

Comment: It's just the navigation hotkeys as far as I know. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#orbit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Go to *Keymap > 3D View > 3d View (Global) > View Axis*.
There are many drop-downs that say *View Axis* but look for the ones that are bound to *Alt drag-Middle Mouse*. There should be four of those and they all should be right next to each other. Click on them and they should have a little tab that says *Direction* and a dropdown list *North*, *South*, etc. That's how you know you have the right ones.

[image]

Comment: Ah ok. Your camera rotate hotkey addition must have reset those because they're normally the default settings.